# How can I integrate a third party authenticator into my Blazor WASM application?

Tags: authentication, blazor, authorization, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am attempting to use software made by a small team over at hello.dev (not to be confused with Microsoft Hello), and I'm struggling to implement it in my Blazor WASM app.  I have successfully implemented it in Blazor server previously, but it seems that I'm misunderstanding something about how WASM works differently. My fundamental problem is that I don't know how to check the authorization state in WASM.

It begins in my Server/Program.cs, where I register the services required.

```
// For OIDC Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
{
    opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opt.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddCookie().AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://issuer.hello.coop";
        options.ClientId = configurationBuilder["HelloAuthentication:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = configurationBuilder["HelloAuthentication:ClientSecret"];
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("name");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
    });

var app = builder.Build();

// For Authentication
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Then, the button along with the JS scripts they provide hit my LoginController.cs, as shown below.

```
    [Route("/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("oidc")]
        public async Task Login(string RedirectUri)
        {
            var props = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = RedirectUri
            };

            await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("oidc", props);
        }

        [HttpGet("logout")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
            return Redirect("/");
        }
    }
```

In my Blazor Server app, I was then able to wrap the components of the App.razor with a , and then retrieve the current user and claims wherever I wanted to with a

```
[CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authState { get; set; }
```

by doing:

```
var currentUser = (await authState).User;
```

However, in WASM, that throws an error because I have not registered the AuthenticationStateProvider to support the . Registration also requires an auth state provider that I don't seem to have, and none of the examples I read through match what I have going on well enough for me to wrap my head around it. Can someone clue me in on the missing pieces here? I have been following tutorials for several days now and none of them seem to perform the way that I want them to.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, asked the question right before a breakthrough. I built a custom state provider based off of some examples online. I also built an authentication service that references a new API in my Login controller, CurrentUserInfo(), which returns User information.  All this allowed me to add the service for the AuthenticationStateProvider, and can retrieve user information using a custom override for the GetAuthenticationStateAsync. In the highly unlikely circumstance that anyone is trying to do the same thing, you can message me for more information.